# How to send a link through an email sent to an SMS Gateway

Tags: email, sms, sms-gateway

So I'm trying to send a link (https://go.mynt.pw/blah) to an SMS gateway. I've tried sending it through the SMS email address (vtext.com) and the MMS email address (vzwpix.com), and none of the messages I've sent have successfully gone through.

Now, I assume that in this case, the SMS/MMS gateway only accept plaintext, but is there a way to format the link in the message I send that it seems like it is in plaintext, rather than a link?

Answer (score 0):

SMS message is plain text message, it's not possible to add markup text, so short answer is no, you can't.

Nevertheless, most handsets nowadays show text starting with http:// as a link you can click and open in browser. Some even show two words separated by a dot (no spaces) like a link too. The latest is useful because you can save 7 characters from a 160 characters message.

In addition, if your messages meets some extra requirements, you can get also a preview of the website you are linking to in the messages app: the link must be at the beginning or end of the message and the webpage you are linking to must have declared an image in the meta property og:title.